# Two modules with the same name - mocking issue

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In jest config `setup.js`, I mock two modules:

```
jest.mock('somePath1/Translator');
jest.mock('somePath2/Translator');
```

When running tests I get this:

```
jest-haste-map: duplicate manual mock found:
  Module name: Translator
  Duplicate Mock path: C:\XXX\dev\YYY\src\components\ZZZ\services\__mocks__\Translator.js
This warning is caused by two manual mock files with the same file name.
Jest will use the mock file found in:
C:\XXX\dev\YYY\src\components\ZZZ\services\__mocks__\Translator.js
 Please delete one of the following two files:
 C:\XXX\dev\YYY\src\common\services\__mocks__\Translator.js
C:\XXX\dev\YYY\src\components\ZZZ\services\__mocks__\Translator.js
```

However, both are needed, some tests use service from once locations, other from the second.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you [tried this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2070#issuecomment-307033243)? Not exactly fun, but might work as a workaround for now.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue since I have multiple modules with the same name, but on different paths under `/src/`.

```
jest-haste-map: duplicate manual mock found: fetch.service
  The following files share their name; please delete one of them:
    * <rootDir>/src/modules/order/__mocks__/fetch.service.ts
    * <rootDir>/src/modules/restaurant/__mocks__/fetch.service.ts
```

After some research, I updated the `jest.config.ts` so it includes:

`modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/.*/__mocks__"]`

this change made the warning to dissapear :9

Answer (score -1):

you could try using a `beforeEach()` and calling `jest.resetModules()` from inside it. Then just mock your dependency on a test by test basis:

```
describe("some test", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
       jest.resetModules();
    });

    test("Some test", () => {
        jest.mock("somePath1/Translator");
        // run tests here
    });

    test("Some other test", () => {
        jest.mock("somePath2/Translator");
        // run tests here
    });
});
```

This will clear your mocks before each test so you shouldn't have any collisions with file names.